# How to recover Ubuntu from text mode?

Tags: 12.04, unity, xserver, text-mode

My Ubuntu no longer starts in graphical mode, it starts in text mode.

If I try to run `startx` I receive `unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory`

How can I reinstall XServer and Unity?

What `apt-get remove` and `apt-get install` should I follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this works for you:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver*

sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall xorg
```

Comment: Worked with your command but only after I put the command `sudo apt-get remove xserver*`, thanks

Comment: Really thank you for your feedback. I hope that the code is now ok @EduardFlorinescu

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver*
sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall xorg
```