# How to recover Ubuntu from text mode

Tags: 16.04, networking, text-mode

My Ubuntu 16.04 no longer starts in graphical mode.

I have tried with [this](https://itsfoss.com/failed-to-start-session-ubuntu-14-04/) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402982/how-to-recover-ubuntu-from-text-mode) guide, but doesnt work because I cant connect to internet. With `ping 8.8.8.8` I get `connect: Network is unreachable` and googling I havent find a solution. Do you know how I can connect to internet?

This problem arose when restarting session after having uninstalled some packages.

Output of `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop`: `dpkg-query: package 'ubuntu-desktop' is not installed and no information is available`
. Because I cant connect to internet in that computer I cant install anything, including `ubuntu-desktop`.

[Content](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dWkerb96eAz6d7gSTJaYjyZdmNfPOmrUIQ/view?usp=sharing) of `/etc/default/grub`

[Output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MarbnrsqwVZPLRzI8ClfqtehO7-AftXkSw/view?usp=sharing) of `sudo systemctl status ligthdm.service`

[Output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q0pUbqEZ8SqnTlvxDMgc6cZ0RSl794yTpw/view?usp=sharing) of `sudo journalctl -xe`

Answer (score 2):

Run these commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
$ sudo systemctl enable lightdm
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

The last of the three commands should be sufficient.  Run all three if there is a problem.  They all should do the same, but sometimes the first two fails.

Comment: I run the last one and then all three but doesnt work

Comment: @DiegoSilvera What is the content of your `/etc/default/grub` file?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Does `sudo systemctl start lightdm` bring up the GUI login manager?

Comment: `Failed to start lightd.service: Unit lightd.service not found`

Comment: The service name is `lighdm` not `lightd`.

Comment: Sorry, `Job for lightdm.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ligthdm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details`

Comment: @DiegoSilvera, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1023849/edit) and update your question with the output of the suggested commands: `sudo systemctl status ligthdm.service` and `sudo journalctl -xe`.

Comment: @pa4080 I edit the question